# How can I undo my delete button when I press it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

```
  const deleteCustomer = (ID) => {
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure to delete?")) {
      Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/stats/delete/${ID}`, {timeout: 10).then(
        (response) => {
          setCustomerList(
            customerList.filter((val) => {
              return val.ID != ID;
            })
          );
        }
      );
    }
  };
const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5; //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited + customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString(
        "en-CA"
      );
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      const my_serial = key + pageNumber * customersPerPage;

      return (
        <tr>
          {/*}
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
      
          <td>{my_serial + 1}</td>
      */}
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <td>
            <select
              onChange={(event) => {
                setNewContacted(event.target.value);
              }}
            >
              <option value="" selected disabled hidden>
                Select Yes/No
              </option>
              <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
              <option value="No">No</option>
            </select>
            <button
              className="btn btn-primary"
              onClick={() => {
                updateCustomerContacted(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Update
            </button>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button
              className="btn btn-danger"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteCustomer(val.ID);
              }}
            >
              Delete
            </button>
```

How can I have an undo function in my delete button in CRUD table?
I have a delete function on my button, is it possible to add an undo function when I delete? and possibly a confirmation message.

On the delete button right at the bottom of the code, it calls function onClick.

If you look at my delete function I have a popup confirmation which will prompt cancel or Yes, when I click yes how can I have a flash message that I can press undo to undo the delete?

Comment: there are multiple options here. 

1. You could first do the "deletes" only clientside by just filtering them out of the state without Axios.delete, so you can then go back if you keep track of the delete id's. But be sure to evntually when you leave the page to really do the deletes
2. You could do the delete but save  the deletedCustomers, so if you want to go back you do an axios.post with that data again.
3. You could filter out the client first out of the state. Then have a setTimeout period for for example 10 seconds. during that period you can show undo, otherwise axios.delete

Comment: @JelteHomminga seems like 3 is the easiest? how can i do it in my code

Comment: @JelteHomminga I'm able to add a timeout say 10s to axios.delete but what about the rest?

Comment: @JelteHomminga However, I feel that, its like setting a timeout period for undo first then retrieving the record

Comment: Yes so the setTimeout returns an id. With that id you can cancel the setTimeout with the undo button. Also with the undo you have to put back the item you filtered out, or refetch the unfiltered data again

Comment: @JelteHomminga What do I need to add in my code?